# Prove that if $f \in L^1[0,1]$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \int^1_0 \sin(\frac{x}{n})f(x) dx = \int^1_0 xf(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $\,\,{\rm f} \in L^{1}\left[0,1\right]$, then 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\lbrack%
n\int^{1}_{0}\sin\left(x \over n\right){\rm f}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x
\right\rbrack
= \int^{1}_{0}x{\rm f}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$

my tries using change of variables, and integration by parts were not successful, I'd appreciate your hints or ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|n \int^1_0 \sin(\frac{x}{n})f(x) dx - \int^1_0 xf(x) dx| \leq \int^1_0 |(n\sin(\frac{x}{n})-x)f(x)| dx \leq ||f||_{1}||(n\sin(\frac{x}{n})-x)||_{\infty}$

where the last inequality is Holder's Inequality.

So you just have to show that $n\sin(\frac{x}{n})$ converges to $x$ in $L^{\infty}$ on $[0,1]$.

This is not so bad if you use the Taylor series for $sin(x/n) = x/n - x^{3}/n^{3}+$ higher order terms. Thus, $nsin(x/n)-x = (x - x^{3}/n^{2} + ...) - x =  - x^{3}/n^{2} + $ higher order terms with greater powers of $n$ in the denominator. So as n goes to infinity, $|(n\sin(\frac{x}{n})-x)||_{\infty}$ goes to zero since $x$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks ! Why do I need "uniform" convergence of $n\sin(x/n)$ to $x$ ?

Comment: I edited it to say $L^{\infty}$ although uniform convergence is the same up to a set of measure $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Try to prove that in $[0,1]$, the sequence of functions $$f_n(x)=\frac{n}{x}\sin\frac{x}n$$ is integrable and monotone increasing (and of course $f_n\to 1$). You may assume $f$ is positive to finish off.

Comment: Thanks ! but I do not see where that $x$ in the denominator comes from ? I mean $\frac{n}{x}$ ?

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity So you have $\int_0^1 f_n(x)xf(x)$. Then use monotone convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\sin(\frac{x}{n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}=x$$

Comment: you probably meant $\frac{x}{n}$ in the denominator